# How to reduce the brightness of selected vector objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is a group of elements in Illustrator. I need to make the whole object less bright. One option is to go through each element in the group and alter the color. Another way is to make a rectangle above it with a certain transparency, but then I lose the objects alpha, which is not desirable.

I wonder if there is an easier way to change brightness without losing the transparency.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select all the artwork that you want to make less bright
2. Go to `Edit -> Edit Colors -> Saturate...`
3. Check the `Preview` check mark to see the results immediately
4. Decrease the intensity until the objects are less bright.

Comment: Excellent, I would never find myself :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Select all the artwork that you want to make less bright
2. Go to Edit -> Edit Colors -> Recolor Artwork
3. Check the Preview check mark to see the results immediately
4. Check the Edit (picture) [image][image][image]

Comment: Where is the preview checkmark?